# Minimizing an Integral of function by derivation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, supervised-learning

Currently I am reading [ESL](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12.pdf). I am struggling to unterstand the step 2.15 to 2.16 in Chapter 2.4.

[image]

The authors mention that the stationary function can be found by differentiation. The commentary [by Weatherwax and Epstein](https://www.waxworksmath.com/Authors/G_M/Hastie/WriteUp/Weatherwax_Epstein_Hastie_Solution_Manual.pdf) develops this step in more detail.

[image]

Why is $\ \dfrac{d}{ d \beta} \int (y-x^T\beta)^2 Pr(dx, dy) =  \int \dfrac{d}{ d \beta}  (y-x^T\beta)^2 Pr(dx, dy)$, that is differentiating the integral partially is equivalent to differentiating the function inside the integral? Any links or explanations are much appreciated.

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign.

Comment: @Bor Is Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, I want to make sure that I understand correctly that when you say "deriving," you mean "differentiating".

What you are asking is called "differentiating under the integral sign" and is covered in basic calculus classes. If you still have your calculus textbook, you might want to do a quick review before going on in machine learning. I don't mean that condescendingly, just a suggestion.

The method is called the *Leibnitz Integration Rule*. You can read about it [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf) with examples, and an interesting anecdote from Richard Feynmann.
Working through the steps:

Notice that $EPE$ is a function of $\beta$ only because the dependence on $x$ and $y$ is being integrated out.

$$
\begin{align} 
\frac{d EPE}{d \beta} & = \frac{d}{d \beta} \int (y - x^T\beta)^2Pr(dx,dy) \\ 
& = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (y - x^T\beta)^2 Pr(dx,dy) ]] \\
& \text{using the chain rule...} \\
& = \int -2(y - x^T\beta)Pr(dx,dy) \\
& = -2 \int (y - x^T\beta)Pr(dx,dy)
\end{align} 
$$

The partial derivative is needed *inside* the integral because we have not yet integrated out $x$ and $y$, so the function we are differentiating is *still* a function of those variables.

Comment: My question is: why is $\ \dfrac{d}{ d \beta} \int (y-x^T\beta)^2 Pr(dx, dy) =  \int \dfrac{d}{ d \beta}  (y-x^T\beta)^2 Pr(dx, dy)$. Or  expressed as functions $\ \dfrac{d}{ d \beta} F(f(\beta)) =  F(\dfrac{d}{ d \beta}  f(\beta)) $ Edited question for more clarity.

Comment: It's called the _Leibnitz Integration Rule_. I've edited my answer with this and corrected a mistake.